# What is the difference between Local Disk and New Volume?

Tags: operating-system, partitioning

We have a product ,while doing some operation we found this error "`Logical disk 'C:' was not found"` . When i checked my "C" folder i saw its named as '`New Volume (C:)`' , but when i changed to '`Local Disk (C:)`' , the error which i was getting gone. Can any body tell me the reason behind it.

These all are my doubts
a> if 'C' folder name is '`New Volume (C:)` ' what does '`New Volume`' stands  is it simply a folder name? then what does `(C:)` stands  is it the one understood by OS?

b>if 'C' folder name is '`Local Disk (C:)` ' what does '`Local Disk`' stands  is it simply a folder name? then what does `(C:)` stands

Comment: Would be a better fit over at server fault : http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.ehow.com/facts_7443060_difference-physical-volumes-hard-drives_.html

Comment: After readind the contents still i am confusing ,the difference between Local Disk and New Volume

Comment: So Local Disk and New Volume are name which we gave and "C" is drive name which we gave at OS installation time or partition?